# Portainer not able to list the running containers on Rancher OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rancher

I am trying portainer and trying to connect remote host. I am getting error failure on retrieve the containers. when I try with Docker -H remote:2375 info on portainer server I am getting docker is running on host error.

Can anyone help me on this?

I am trying with AWS Rancher machine. Installed portainer on rancher machine. And I am not able to figure out on which port, Docker daemon is running on AWS rancher server.

I did

```
sudo netstat -latuxen | grep docker
```

and tried to connect all ports listed there. but still I am getting the same error.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Portainer needs the Docker API to be exposed in order to manage it.

Portainer can connect to the Docker API in two different ways:

- Using a bind mount to the Docker socket (available on Linux and Docker for Windows (Docker in a VM) only, e.g. no native Windows containers)
- Connecting to the Docker API via TCP (requires you to expose that TCP port in the Docker daemon configuration)

As you've already experienced:

> when I try with Docker -H remote:2375 info on portainer server I am getting docker is running on host error

This means that the Docker API is not exposed via TCP, I suggest that you read more about how to do that in the Docker documentation (this will basically depend on your platform).

For example, here is the documentation part on how to configure the Docker daemon on Ubuntu: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/#/configuring-docker

If you can't connect via `docker -H remote`, neither Portainer will be able to connect unless you're able to start a container locally and use a bind mount to the Docker socket.

I also recommend you to read Portainer documentation, especially the deployment section: https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html

Comment: I tried to expose the docker port as in docker documentation. But rancher OS already come up with  system-docker and docker. But I am not able to figure it out on which port docker is running.